# How to install Pypy for Python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, pypy

I want to install Pypy for python 3.5.3. I am using Windows 10, 64 bits. I have looked in pypy website https://pypy.org/download.html but I cannot find useful information.

Can anyone help me on how to install and how to use pypy?

I have read it makes your code faster so that is why I want to use it

Comment: You're going to have a hard time with that, since [PyPy's latest release](https://pypy.org/download.html) only supports the Python 3.5 language standard. A suggestion: Download a binary distribution (also from the linked page), not the src package.

Answer (score 1):

All binary versions are packaged in a tar.bz2 or zip file. When uncompressed, they run in-place. For now you can uncompress them either somewhere in your home directory or, say, in /opt, and if you want, put a symlink from somewhere like /usr/local/bin/pypy to /path/to/pypy_expanded/bin/pypy. Do not move or copy the executable pypy outside the tree – put a symlink to it, otherwise it will not find its libraries.