# Running pypy with windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.7, pypy

I am new to programming and I'm attempting to run pypy 3.7 on windows for a project and have had zero success. My partner found 
[these instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltkXs.png) but following them didn't seem to work. Is the problem with the prompt, installation, python, anything else?? Any and all help would be very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It could have been any number of things. Did you encounter any error messages that might help unravel this mystery? Also could you just link to the answer instead of uploading a photo of a computer screen?

Answer (score 0):

You may have an incompatible Python version. PyPy doesn't support the latest version of Python 3.5, so you may need to install an earlier version of Python.

Also follow this thread: [How to install Pypy for Python 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507344/how-to-install-pypy-for-python-3-5)